# Which is preferred in professional java applications SQL in jstl or in the servlets only

Tags: java, mysql, web-applications, jstl, long-polling

Okay Guys, just a little of a professional question here.

I am building a web application for a small company. The language I am using is java for a couple of reasons, one because it is my home language, two because of the amount of data and scalability that the application will need in the future.

My question has nothing to do with my language choice but more with the implementation of a few ideas. I am building an appointments calendar, and current events table, as well as a Data Driven bar, bubble, and plot graph for the amount of traffic that current events are getting.

I will be using long polls to keep  the view current with the database.

My question is in doing this should I build a class to take care of the query and just reload the entire page every (N seconds) to get the updated data, or should I build the long polling into the div using jstl sql query to keep the data current and only reload the div every (N Seconds).

I understand if this is considered a weak question, but I am honestly learning this as I go and you guys have always been a great source of information.

So Far I have tried passing to a servlet to reload a page instead of reloading directly on the page by just reloading the div, I like this approach because it allows me to separate out the processes and leave the web stuff with the web stuff and the data in the model, what I am not liking about this is that you can see the flicker of the page load when you update the information.

I haven't tried the use of this technique in the calendar yet or with the bar graphs because honestly I have been racking ideas on how to approach the issue first, I want to try just refreshing the div instead of the entire page but if I am using a servlet to do that I won't be able to do so I will have to reload the entire page. I therefore would be using the jstl query tags to accomplish this, but I am not 100% sure that this is the practical and professional approach.

Comment: The archetypal "wall of text" is not easy to read.  Please use line/paragraph breaks.

Comment: and tell us what have you tried so far, what do you like vs dislike

Comment: I hope you don't format your code as you format your prose...

Comment: I think @BoristheSpider's remark was a subtle dig and my guess is he is referring to the well known quote by [Grady Booch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grady_Booch): "Clean code is simple and direct. Clean code reads like well-written prose. Clean code never obscures the designers’ intent but rather is full of crisp abstractions and straightforward lines of control."

Answer (score 2):

SQL does not belong in JSTL or any other view.

I don't think SQL belongs in servlets either, unless you package and deploy them as separate REST services.  They should stand on their own and not be tied to any web UI.

User interfaces come and go; services and back end data evolve more slowly.

The current fashion would make web user interfaces using HTML5, CSS3, JavaScript, and jQuery as the basis.  (You can layer on top any framework you like.)   The back end would be REST services.

Comment: I agree with you here, which is where my inner argument resides, I have thought about building a restful service to gather the information, but to be honest I am still not up to par with rest, I haven't had a very long time to work on it. Any ideas where I could go to really crash head first into it, and in grain it into my repertoire

Comment: @RichardDavy then start working on some tests about REST services. It is not that hard to provide and consume.

Comment: I'd recommend forgetting about REST or how you expose remotely.  Write a POJO DAO that does your database access, test it thoroughly, and then expose it any way you wish: REST, SOAP, EJB, or anything else.